# Loading Sequence of JQuery objects in Firefox different than in Chrome/Opera?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loading, show-hide

I have problems with the loading sequence of jQuery objects in a HTML and Javascript  file when executed on Firefox.
I have several `<div>` and `<button>` tags with different `id`. The page starts with following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#id_1").show();
   $("#id_2").hide();
   $("#id_3").hide();
   ...
});

$(document).ready(function () {
   $.getJSON("JSON_file.json", function (json) {
      if (json.option[number] == "b") {
         $("#id_2").show()
      };

      if (json.option[number] == "c") {
         $("#id_3").show()
      };
   });
});
</script>
```

In Chrome and Opera I have no issues with this code. The objects "#id_2" and "#id_3" are not visible on load.
However in Firefox both "#id_2" and "#id_3" are visible for a short moment before being hidden. But I don´t want them to be visible at the begin.

I use localhost to open the files.

Does anybody know what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: hide element using CSS rather than jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello You can add default hide call in div and then remove that call on condition basic.
Like

```
<div id="#id_1" class='hide'>
My Div 1
</div>
<div id="#id_2" class='hide'>
My Div 1
</div>
<div id="#id_3" class='hide'>
My Div 1
</div>
```

Now your script code

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function () {
   $.getJSON("JSON_file.json", function (json) {
      if (json.option[number] == "b") {
         $("#id_2").removeClass('hide')
      };

      if (json.option[number] == "c") {
         $("#id_3").removeClass('hide')
      };
   });
});
</script>
```